# Use transient clipboard type with pyobjc

Tags: python, python-3.x, objective-c, macos, pyobjc

I want to copy some text to the clipboard with PyObjC, but mark it as transient so that it doesn't get saved in the clipboard history of various apps which support that.

A normal clipboard copy is straight forward enough

```
from AppKit import *

s = 'text to copy'

pbtype = NSStringPboardType

pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pb.declareTypes_owner_([pbtype], None)
newStr = NSString.stringWithString_(s)
newData = newStr.nsstring().dataUsingEncoding_(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
pb.setData_forType_(newData, pbtype)
```

According to http://nspasteboard.org/Site/Transient.html, in "proper" Objective-C, one can use `@"org.nspasteboard.TransientType"` as the pasteboard type to mark it to be ignored. If I understand correctly, `@` is used for literals that aren't plain string C/C++ literals, but NSString / ObjC literals. So I tried this:

```
from AppKit import *

s = 'text to copy'

pbtype = NSString.stringWithString_("org.nspasteboard.TransientType")

pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pb.declareTypes_owner_([pbtype], None)
newStr = NSString.stringWithString_(s)
newData = newStr.nsstring().dataUsingEncoding_(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
pb.setData_forType_(newData, pbtype)
```

in both examples, `pbtype` seems to be the correct type:

```
>>> type(NSString.stringWithString_("org.nspasteboard.TransientType")) is type(NSStringPboardType)
True
```

But the latter example doesn't work at all (the clipboard gets set to nothing).

I've tried a bunch of things but this is the closest I've got to what "looks" right as compared to native Objective-C code that odes the same thing, but I'm clearly missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: How I interpret [Identifying and Handling Transient or Special Data on the Clipboard](http://nspasteboard.org/): add `NSStringPboardType` with the string as usual and add `org.nspasteboard.TransientType` with dummy data.

Comment: I think I get what you mean @Willeke - If you have a slightly more fleshed out answer feel free to post, otherwise if I can get that working I'll resolve this with an answer

Answer (score 0):

As @Willeke pointed out in the comment under my question, seems like you can set `org.nspasteboard.TransientType` with nil data *after* setting the clipboard:

```
def set_clipboard(text):
    pb.clearContents()
    a = NSArray.arrayWithObject_(text)
    pb.writeObjects_(a)
    pbtype = NSString.stringWithString_("org.nspasteboard.TransientType")
    pb.setData_forType_(None, pbtype)
```